# install python setuptools on linux

Tags: python, linux, centos, setuptools, urllib3

I have machine without internet access, running on CentOS. So I want to install urllib3. I downloaded zip-archive from github, transferred it to my machine, unzip it, and try to execute `python setup.py install` . Then I have an error: `ImportError: No module named setuptools`. 
So I want to install setuptools on CentOS where there is no internet access. Also I doesn't have pip. 
How can I install setuptools? Or maybe install urllib3 right away?

Comment: Which Python version do you want it on?  There are 2+ default installations on Linux, `python` by default is Python 2.7.  You get `python3` as well

Comment: I have Python 2.7.5, and want install on this version

Comment: You can install mini-conda, download the necessary from packages from https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/ and copy those files to a local HTTP server that you declare as a channel.

Comment: Or you can manually copy the *urllib3* dir from the zip into the "site packages" dir (on my *Ubtu* machine it's */usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages*). You can find it in `sys.path`.

Comment: Will it work without setupools?

Comment: Just try it :). As I don't know the *.zip* file structure, I assumed that it contained a dir called *urllib3*. Check whether that dir has an *\_\_init\_\_.py* file (and others) under it. If it does, it should work.

Comment: python-setuptools-0.9.8-7.el7.noarch.rpm http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.5.1804/os/x86_64/Packages/python-setuptools-0.9.8-7.el7.noarch.rpm